# porque da error en el view.xml

Tags: mvc, xml, odoo

estaba configurando el modulo para poder verlo sin estar en modo super usuario pero a la hora de actualizar esso cambios quito el modo usper usuario y vuelvo a ingresar y no me muestra el modulo y en la terminal me manda un un error en mi archivo xml

Adjunto codigo

````
``` <record id="view_presupuesto_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Vista formulario de presupuesto de peliculas</field>
    <field name="model">presupuesto</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <header>
                <button string="Aprobar" type="object" name="aprobar_presupuesto" class="oe_highlight" states="borrador"/>
                <button string="Cancelar" type="object" name="cancelar_presupuesto" states="borrador,aprobado"/>
                <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="borrador,aprobado"/>
            </header>
            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="margin-bottom: 0" attrs="{'invisible': [('dsc_clasificacion', '=', False)]}">
                <field name="dsc_clasificacion" readonly="1" force_save="1" />
            </div>
            <sheet>
            <widget name="web_ribbon" title="Archivado" bg_color="bg-danger" attrs="{'invisible': [('active', '=', True)]}"/>
                <field name="image_1920" widget="image" class="oe_avatar"
                       options="{'preview_image': 'image_128', 'size': ['',128]}"/>

                <div class="oe_tittle">
                    <div class="o_row">
                        <field name="active" invisible="1"/>
                        <h1 styly="display: flex;">
                            <field name="name"
                                   placeholder="Nombre de la pelicula"
                                   required="1"
                                   default_focus="1" class="oe_inline"/>

                            <field name="puntuacion" widget="percentpie" string=" " style="padding-left: 10px" class="oe_inline"/>
                            <field name="puntuacion2" placeholder="Puntuacion de usuario"
                                   class="oe_edit_only oe_inline"/>
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="o_row" style="display: flex;">
                        <field name="Clasificacion" required="1"/>
                        <span class="fa fa-circle" attrs="{'invisible': [('Clasificacion', '=', False), ('fch_estreno', '=', False)]}"
                        style="font-size: 8px; padding:5px;"/>
                        <field name="fch_estreno" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="o_row">
                        <field name="genero_ids" widget="many2many_tags" style="display: flex;"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <group string="Datos principales" style="margin-top: -10px;">
                    <field name="vista_general" placeholder="Vista general..." attrs="{'readonly': [('state','!=', 'borrador')]}"/>
                    <group>
                        <field name="director_id" domain="[('category_id', 'in', [categoria_director_id])]"
                        options="{'no_create': True, 'no_open': True}"/>
                        <field name="categoria_director_id" invisible="1"/>
                        <field name="link_trailer" widget="url"/>
                    </group>
                    <group>
                        <field name="es_libro" widget="boolean_toggle"/>
                        <field name="libro" filename="libro_filename" attrs="{'invisible': [('es_libro', '=', False)]}"/>
                        <field name="libro_filename" invisible="1"/>
                    </group>
                </group>

                <separator string="Detalles"/>

                <notebook>
                    <page string="Presupuesto">
                        <group>
                            <group>
                                <field name="num_presupuesto" readonly="1"/>
                                <field name="fch_creacion" readonly="1"/>
                                <field name="fch_aprobado" readonly="1"/>
                            </group>
                            <group>
                                <field name="currency_id"/>
                                <field name="campos_ocultos" widget="boolean_toggle"/>
                            </group>
                        </group>
                        <field name="detalle_ids">
                            <tree editable="bottom">
                                <control>
                                    <create name="add_product_control" string="Agregar recurso cinematografico"/>
                                </control>
                                <field name="imagen" widget="image" options="{'size': [80,50]}" optional="show"/>
                                <field name="name"/>
                                <field name="descripcion" optional="show"/>
                                <field name="contacto_id" attrs="{'column_invisible': [('parent.campos_ocultos', '=', False)]}"/>
                                <field name="cantidad"/>
                                <field name="precio"/>
                                <field name="importe" readonly="1" force_save="1"/>
                                <field name="currency_id" invisible="1"/>
                            </tree>
                        </field>
                        <group clo="6" class="mt-2 mt-md-0">
                            <group colspan="4">
                                <field name="terminos" nolabel="1" placeholder="Terminos y condiciones..."/>
                            </group>
                            <group class="oe_subtotal_footer oe_right" clspan="2">
                                <field name="base" widget="monetary" options="{'currency_field': 'currency_id'}"/>
                                <field name="impuestos"/>
                                <div class="oe_subtotal_footer_separator oe_line o_td_label">
                                    <laber for="total"/>
                                </div>
                                <field name="total" nolabel="1" class="oe_subtotal_footer_separator" widget="monetary" options="{'currency_field': 'currency_id'}"/>
                            </group>
                            <div class="oe_clear"/>
                        </group>
                    </page>
                    <page string="Otra informacion">
                        <group>
                        <field name="actor_ids" domain="[('category_id', 'in', [categoria_actor_id])]"
                        options="{'no_create': True, 'no_open': True}"
                        widget="many2many_tags"/>
                        <field name="categoria_actor_id" invisible="1"/>
                            <field name="opinion"/>
                        </group>
                        <group>

                        </group>
                    </page>
                </notebook>


            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="view_presupuesto_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Vista lista de presupuesto</field>
    <field name="model">presupuesto</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree decoration-danger="state == 'cancelar'" decoration-success="state == 'aprobado'">
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="num_presupuesto"/>
            <field name="fch_creacion"/>
            <field name="total" sum="importe_total"/>
            <field name="state" widget="badge" decoration-success="state == 'aprobado'" decoration-danger="state == 'cancelar'"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="view_presupuesto_kanban" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Vista kanban del modelo presupuesto</field>
    <field name="model">presupuesto</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <kanban>
            <field name="id"/>
            <field name="currency_id"/>
            <templates>
                <t t-name="kanban-box">
                    <div class="oe_kanban_global_click">
                        <div class="o_kanban_image">
                            <img t-att-src="kanban_image('presupuesto', 'image_128', record.id.raw_value)" class="o_image_64_contain"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="oe_kanban_details">
                            <strong class="oe_kanban_record_tittle">
                                <field name="name"/>
                            </strong>
                            [<field name="Clasificacion"/>]
                       </div>
                        <div>
                            <field name="genero_ids"/>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <field name="total" widget="monetary" options="{'currency_field': 'currency_id', 'field:digits': True}"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </t>
            </templates>
        </kanban>
    </field>
</record>```
````

ya lo estuve revisanso y no encuentro el error y en la terminal manda que hay cosas sin contexto y aparte que ya hay un atributo con el mismo nombre que ya esta instanciado o que ya tiene cosas dentro de como puedo corregir esos errores que me da no se si se apor esoso errores que no me deja ver el modulo sin estar en modo super user porque igua.l tengo bien configurado el archivo csv y tiene permisos para poder verlo sin necesidad de estar en modo super user

Adjunto imagen de la terminal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ese es el error que manda y segun yo no tendria porque mandar esos errores que tendria que hacer o como podria corregirlo y no se si por eso no me permita ver el modulo sin estar en super user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que una vista se vea debe de cumplir varias condiciones.

1. Si estás creando un modulo, debes darle permisos ya sea en el fichero de seguirdad (`ir.model.access.csv`) o desde la interfaz.
2. Tiene que estar ligado a un elemento de menú que a su vez llame a un act_window.

Para darle permisos a un usuario desde la interfaz de odoo escribe en la pantalla de aplicacions "access rights" ó ingresa a
Settings / Technical / Security / Access Rights.

Crea un nuevo permiso escogiendo el modelo que se correponde a tu vista y selecciona "internal user" para el grupo. Dale los 4 permisos. Recarga la pantalla y debería salir el menu.

Comment: eso fue lo que hice pero no funciono

Comment: Si puedes ver la vista en modo super usuario quiere decir que te faltan permisos.

Comment: id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink

acceso_presupuesto_usuario,acceso presupuesto usuario,model_presupuesto,group_pelicula_usuario,1,1,1,1
acceso_presupuesto_detalle_usuario,acceso presupuesto detalle usuario,model_presupuesto_detalle,group_pelicula_usuario,1,1,1,1
acceso_recuso_cinematografico_usuario,acceso recuso cinematografico usuario,model_recuso_cinematografico,group_pelicula_usuario,1,1,1,1
acceso_genero_usuario,acceso genero usuario,model_genero,group_pelicula_usuario,1,1,1,1

Comment: acceso_presupuesto_administrador,acceso presupuesto administrador,model_presupuesto,group_pelicula_administrador,1,1,1,1
acceso_presupuesto_detalle_administrador,acceso presupuesto detalle administrador,model_presupuesto_detalle,group_pelicula_administrador,1,1,1,1
acceso_recuso_cinematografico_administrador,acceso recuso cinematografico administrador,model_recuso_cinematografico,group_pelicula_administrador,1,1,1,1
acceso_genero_administrador,acceso genero administrador,model_genero,group_pelicula_administrador,1,1,1,1

Comment: eso es lo que tengo en el ir.model.acces.csv

Comment: no se si asi este bien

Comment: Registraste ese archivo en el manifest?

Comment: 'security/security.xml',
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'data/categoria.xml',
        'data/secuencia.xml',
        'views/presupuesto_views.xml',
        'views/menu.xml',

Comment: si lo puse tal y como viene en su path

Comment: Si creaste ese permiso recientemente, y los otros permisos si los está tomando, posiblemente tengas que 1. Reiniciar el servidor de pruebas. . 2.Actualizar directamente la aplicacion en la lista de app. 3. Desinstalar el modulo y volver a instalar. 4. Desinstalar el modulo, eliminar el modulo desde la lista de apps. Cambiar el nombre del modulo. Instalar de nuevo. Posiblemente hay un error que no te esta apareciendo en consola (Suele pasar)

Comment: ok voy a ver si algo de eso funciona

Comment: nop sigue igual

Comment: y sigue mandando los mimos errores del xml

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140125/discussion-between-carlos-baez-and-legna).

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140194/discussion-between-carlos-baez-and-legna).